# Como deixar campo Choices sem valor default

Tags: python, django

Atualmente tenho esta classe com um field choice, tentei deixar por padrão "deufault=None" podem ele permanece trazendo o campo preenchido com Royal Flush,
se mudo para outro choice existente ele aceita, estou fazendo algo errado?

```
class Sessao(models.Model):
    MAO_DERROTA = (
        ('Royal Flush', 'Royal Flush'),
        ('Straight Flush', 'Straight Flush'),
        ('Quadra', 'Quadra'),
        ('Full House', 'Full House'),
        ('Flush', 'Flush'),
        ('Straight', 'Straight'),
        ('Trinca', 'Trinca'),
        ('Dois pares', 'Dois pares'),
        ('Um Par', 'Um Par'),
        ('Carta Alta', 'Carta Alta'),

    )
    data_ini_sessao = models.DateField(verbose_name='Data inicial da partida')
    torneio = models.ForeignKey(Torneio, verbose_name='Torneio', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buy_in = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Buy-in')
    jogadores = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Qtd jogadores')
    premio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Vlr Premio')
    saldo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Saldo da partida')
    colocacao = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Colocação')
    data_fin_sessao = models.DateField(verbose_name='Data final da partida')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tempo = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Tempo')
    comentario_sessao = models.TextField(blank=True)
    mao_derrota = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MAO_DERROTA, default=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere `MAO_DERROTA` para:

```
MAO_DERROTA = (
    ('','..........'),  
    ('Royal Flush', 'Royal Flush'),
    ('Straight Flush', 'Straight Flush'),
    ('Quadra', 'Quadra'),
    ('Full House', 'Full House'),
    ('Flush', 'Flush'),
    ('Straight', 'Straight'),
    ('Trinca', 'Trinca'),
    ('Dois pares', 'Dois pares'),
    ('Um Par', 'Um Par'),
    ('Carta Alta', 'Carta Alta'),
)
```

Troque os pontinhos `(.......)`, pelo o que vc quiser.

Comment: Ah certo, caso seja um campo obrigatório ele não deixa salvar estando nessa primeira opção correto?

Comment: teste, deu certinho, até a obrigação de escolha, muito obrigado Sidon

Comment: Sim, mas o ideal é voce tratar isso e avisar para o usuario.

Comment: coloquei assim:     MAO_DERROTA = (
        ('', 'Escolha sua mao'),

Comment: Boa! Django is badass! :-)